# Parsing embedded quotation marks in csv

Tags: r, parsing, csv

I am trying to read a csv containing rows like this

```
"MARTIN, ERIC ROBERT",Republican Party,04,House, ...
"SUMMERS, SEAN E",Republican Party,04,House, ...
```

Is it possible to read this using `readr` or `read.csv`?

[Here](http://www.fec.gov/data/CandidateSummary.do?format=csv&election_yr=2012) is the file from the U.S. Federal Election Commission website.

```
require(readr)
candSumDat = read.csv('CandidateSummaryAction.csv', quote="", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL, sep = ",")
candDat = read_csv('CandidateSummaryAction.csv')
```

Unfortunately, when I get complicated quotation marks in some rows, `readr` totally screws up the row parsing.

```
2012-04-17,[2012],O,2012,H2KY04139,4,"ADKINS, WILLIAM R. ""BILL""",Democratic Party,04,House,Open seat,H,['04'],C,[2012],KY,DEM
```

How can I solve this? Should I just overwrite the rows by hand? Is there a way to deal with it automatedly?

`read.csv` doesn't report which rows are the cause of its `more columns than column names` error, unfortunately, though as MrFlick shows in the comments, this particular line isn't a problem for it.

Comment: What's the problem? This works: `read.csv(text='"ADKINS, WILLIAM R. ""BILL""",Democratic Party,04,House', header=F)`

Comment: Yeah, that's true. `readr` reports errors for that line in the csv. `read.csv` doesn't report specific lines, so I guess that package is having a different problem (but harder to track down than readr's and fread's problems). So I'll edit the question to specify.

Comment: @MrFlick Ok I think I've clarified the problem somewhat, and added the file and code to make it easier to try it out.

Comment: You can use a site like http://csvlint.io/ to validate your CSV. It's clear you have an improperly formatted CSV file. Not sure how you made it but there are clearly problems with quotes in various lines.

Comment: @MrFlick Unfortunately that site produces an error for this file.